# req.app.get('env') === 'development' возвращает false

Tags: node.js, package

Я использую:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production && node ./src/bin/www",
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon ./src/bin/www"
  },
```

Но почему-то при проверки `req.app.get('env') === 'development'` возвращается false, когда вывожу значение `req.app.get('env')` в консоль, то там `development`, я так же пытался сравнивать через `==`, но результат тот же.

UPD:
Я вывел значение `req.app.get('env')` в кавычках и увидел там лишний пробел, из-за чего он возникает и как от него избавиться?

UPD:
Если писать `set NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon ./src/bin/www`, то все работает, но такой вариант читать не удобно, как это делается по нормальному?

Comment: `... NODE_ENV='production' ...`

Comment: Можно по точнее? Просто значение в кавычках не помогало, как в двойных так и одинарных.

Comment: Странно, конечно.. Можете просто trim() использовать, или .env файл использовать

Comment: Я думал насчет .env файла, но это же придется каждый раз менять значение в файле?